# Execute a command block in XQuery in a java application

Tags: java, xpath, xquery

I'm using a xHive Database with Java. In my Java application I need to call the same xQuery function many times like this.

```
libDev.executeXQuery("import module namespace download = 'http://xquery.myxq.com.br/download' at 'http://localhost:8080/WebUpdate/xq/download.xq';
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4025')");

libDev.executeXQuery("import module namespace download = 'http://xquery.myxq.com.br/download' at 'http://localhost:8080/WebUpdate/xq/download.xq';
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4026')");
```

I want to make a command block like this and execute it only one time. 
There are any way to do this in xquery?

```
libDev.executeXQuery("import module namespace download = 'http://xquery.myxq.com.br/download' at 'http://localhost:8080/WebUpdate/xq/download.xq';
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4025')
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4026')";
```

When I try to run this block I get this error:

```
com.xhive.error.xquery.XhiveXQueryParseException: query:3:1:XQUERY_PARSE_ERROR:
```

no viable alternative at input 'download' (NCName) (XPST0003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your expressions in a sequence constructor, i.e. `(expr1, expr2)`

```
libDev.executeXQuery("import module namespace download = 'http://xquery.myxq.com.br/download' at 'http://localhost:8080/WebUpdate/xq/download.xq';
(
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4025'),
download:updateDeviceData('pc', '0040-A72D-4026')
)";
```

Comment: To be precise, the sequence operator is the coma. The parenthesis is used, like in many languages, to change the precedence when needed. They don't hurt, but are indeed not necessary in this case ;-)